# Force mount NTFS partition (damaged blocks)

Tags: partitioning, mount, windows, ntfs, badblocks

Apparently my hard disk has decided to get damaged and my Windows NTFS partition is not accessible. I have a dual boot, but the Windows one would not initialise (maybe not solvable).

I will more likely have to format that partition, but I was wondering if there is any chance to recover the data (mounting under Ubuntu).

The usual mounting commands are throwing errors at me, probably due to the damaged blocks. I know I can use  `badblocks` in order to try to recover the partition, but I'm not sure if after using it I will be able to mount it under Ubuntu without losing the data.

So... is it safe? Or, is there any other way to solve that problem? Or... have I lost the data completely? :(

**EDIT:**

I have run `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda2` and the output is the following:

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK
NTFS partition /dev/sda2 was processed successfully.
```

So... apparently no bad blocks... Very strange, since I still can't mount that partition, even if I try to force the mount:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/flash/wind -o force

ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Error de entrada/salida
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Error de entrada/salida
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```